# Imprimir valor de array em bash pelo shell_exec do PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, shell-script

Eu tenho um outro script, mas simplifiquei para esse para simular o problema que persiste.

**teste.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
ARRAY=('like' 'a' 'stone')
echo ${ARRAY[0]}
```

No arquivo abaixo, em outro momento já me certifiquei que o `shell_exec` está de fato executando o comando acima.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$comando = file_get_contents("teste.sh");
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(shell_exec($comando));
echo "</pre>";
```

Aqui estou esperando que imprima `like`, mas o resultado sempre vem nulo como abaixo.

**Saída**

```
NULL
```

Porem, se eu mudo o meu `teste.sh` para apenas `php -v`, ele imprime a versão do meu PHP. O que não é o que eu quero, mas serve de tira teima.

**Saída**

```
string(235) "PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) (built: May 19 2016 19:05:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
"
```

Aí eu fico encucado, como que ele não é capaz de imprimir o que eu estou esperando ? O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não fez nada de errado.

Esse problema acontece devido ao *script* ser interpretado de forma diferente em dois ambientes distintos.

Ao executar `./teste1.sh` o sistema irá olhar para o [`shebang`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang), que neste caso é `#!/bin/bash` e irá executar o *script* usando [`/bin/bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). Se você executá-lo digitando: `sh script1.sh` ele irá executar usando o `/bin/sh`.

No Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` é tipicamente um atalho para `/bin/dash` (veja: `ls -l /bin/sh`) um [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) que [não suporta `arrays`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch45_34.htm), e essa é a origem do problema.

Ao abrir uma nova janela do terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> o ambiente provavelmente será [`/bin/bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), no PHP ao executar a [função `shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php) o *script* provavelmente será executado usando `/bin/sh`. Teste o código:

```
<?php

echo shell_exec("echo $0"); // sh?
```

Para resolver isto, você deve executar o *script* usando o `/bin/bash`, veja abaixo duas formas:

1. Executar o *script* usando o `bash`:

   ```
   <?php

   $conteudo = file_get_contents("script1.sh");
   echo shell_exec("bash -c '$conteudo'");
   ```

   <sub>A [opção `-c`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bash-options.html) indica para ao `bash` para ler os comandos da variável `$conteudo`.</sub>
2. Indicar o `bash` e o arquivo diretamente na [função `shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php):

   ```
   <?php

   echo shell_exec("bash script1.sh");
   ```

Comment: Opá, Deu certinho. Salvou minha vida. Muito obrigado @zekk. Optei por usar mais a primeira forma.